# VBA Filter based on time ending in a multiple of 5 seconds

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter a date/time field to only show dates/times that are off the 5-second mark (so ending in 0 or 5). 
This line does not give me an error, but it doesn't work either. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

`sht.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="or(second()<>5,second()<>0)"`

Here is a screenshot of the field:

[image: column in sheet]

So if the filter worked properly, it should have shown that first record. But it's not showing anything. The filter returns an empty set. I've thought about trying stuff with modulo but haven't figured out how to write it correctly. Any ideas? TIA!

Comment: I'd use a helper column here, if that's an option.

Comment: Hi @BigBen thank you for your response! Would you mind elaborating? What would the helper column hold?

Comment: something like so in a helper column `=MOD(SECOND($A2),5)` would give 0's for the seconds which are multiples of 5

Comment: Assuming your values are in column A, place this formula into B1 and drag down to give you just the last digit as a character. Then you can test for "0" or "5" easily 
        =RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"),1)

Comment: Yeah I could do it that way. Thanks. While the ideal solution would be to do it straight through the filter code line in the VBA, this will at least work. Thank you both

Comment: If you're willing to do it without .AutoFilter, you could do everything in vba by using application.worksheetfunction with the above functions, for example. But to directly apply .AutoFilter is challenging because of the way Date/Times are handled in Excel. Perhaps it can be done and someone smarter than I will explain it to us ;)